# How to make greenplum a columnar database?

Tags: database, greenplum

By default, Greenplum is a row-based database but it is stated that data can be stored in a columnar manner. How do I change the data from row to columnar form in Greenplum?

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I found the solution
try:
The WITH clause of the CREATE TABLE command is used to declare the storage options of the table. If not declared, the table will be created as a row-oriented heap table. Tables that use column-oriented storage must also be append-only tables. For example, to create a column-oriented table:
''''CREATE TABLE bar (a int, b text)
WITH (appendonly=true, orientation=column)
DISTRIBUTED BY (a);''''

Comment: To add to this, the explanation can be found here: https://gpdb.docs.pivotal.io/43250/admin_guide/ddl/ddl-storage.html